# JQuery validation url validation goes in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using following code to validate the URL:

```
var urlregex = new RegExp(
    "^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
if (true === urlregex.test(textval.trim())) {
    return true;
}
return false
```

when I gives a long url (more than 200 characters )  then it going in infinite loop and killing my web page with giving message "the following page has become unresponsive you can wait till it become responsive or kill"

Comment: it is not connected to jQuery at all. This is about pure JS.

Comment: Thanks :) removed jQuery tag

Comment: `&amp;` inside character class? It looks fishy.

Comment: No problem:) I think the only option here is to use a more simple regular expression. I am not sure about real need to check in JavaScript so exactly.

Comment: is it because of &amp?

Comment: You are using nested quantifiers, which is a very probable cause of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Where did you get that regex, and why do you think it's suitable for your task?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Nested quantifier won't always cause problem. Just that in this case, the last part with nest quantifier is the culprit...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: this regex is working perfect me in all case except above case.

Comment: Yes, so you can either ignore that case or write a new regex that doesn't lead to exponential backtracking, right? Whoever wrote that regex didn't really know what they were doing, so I'm quite skeptical if it's a good idea to try and fix this (instead of using a proper URL validator, which is most likely *not* a regex).

Comment: I have changed that regex

Comment: So do you still need an answer? (If not, just delete this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if (condition === true) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

is an antipattern. Use

```
return (condition === true);
```

Apart from that, instead of rolling your own regex for URL matching, use [a tried-and-tested one](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls).

```
var urlregex = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;
```